# Geting out put from Script Html agility pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

i am having problem that this following script generates Email address when page is loaded and i want to parse that email how can i do that?

```
tr> 
    <td align='right' class='generalinfo_left' >Email Address:</td> 
    <td class='generalinfo_right'><script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[    
var o3752aaa9bb29d904adeb88838117fd7c = String.fromCharCode(109);var f03de7e643c296e211edddbc3197b33f6 = String.fromCharCode(97);var k7c3bf82468602c0f8dff4950e4b6ff1e = String.fromCharCode(105);var b3eaa633e44451be8df1fa47d75149934 = 'l';var ma2fa16c3a3f532b780aaf0fa5a5b75c6 = 't';var re0c13fc69c03925782867a0540f8c084 = 'o';var j335f1365672123d1fcaf9a83b76f1b7b = String.fromCharCode(58);var f32820e1c54cbc3fa0d418cd1c195eaec = String.fromCharCode(105);var y8c24ea00a7a1edf1c01f794d487697e3 = String.fromCharCode(110);var bcc0ad4f628e703f9ff6e25b87b77ec34 = 'f';var c985c961c7ee85fe6a25d5a66fb421745 = String.fromCharCode(111);var z5ab4e3bdc353d621cea5babcc5dca417 = String.fromCharCode(64);var s4e087167cd0bac466344e72016511172 = String.fromCharCode(97);var re26f6ae180723793af62bc36d5ab2530 = String.fromCharCode(108);var ye1b53d01de118079a38de5e951586731 = 'c';var g9fc5710c9266ce08afbe4da24702dfdd = String.fromCharCode(105);var k5cd5ea1bac40fdbb8b133b7e356809c6 = String.fromCharCode(118);var fcd6e4771e956e270c6897d24ca51c256 = String.fromCharCode(97);var y9d7854a5921fa2be88c8cd72c7e2884e = String.fromCharCode(114);var xa58bea1ecad6fe7d2c736aab1df2df44 = '.';var e4569f6c98804675f7117a84abb0b8d5c = 'c';var o4d2081e2344020922dcb924690c9972e = 'o';var af150185e5eef8ecd8dc1b0a4977c7d55 = String.fromCharCode(109);document.write("<a href='" + o3752aaa9bb29d904adeb88838117fd7c + f03de7e643c296e211edddbc3197b33f6 + k7c3bf82468602c0f8dff4950e4b6ff1e + b3eaa633e44451be8df1fa47d75149934 + ma2fa16c3a3f532b780aaf0fa5a5b75c6 + re0c13fc69c03925782867a0540f8c084 + j335f1365672123d1fcaf9a83b76f1b7b  + f32820e1c54cbc3fa0d418cd1c195eaec + y8c24ea00a7a1edf1c01f794d487697e3 + bcc0ad4f628e703f9ff6e25b87b77ec34 + c985c961c7ee85fe6a25d5a66fb421745 + z5ab4e3bdc353d621cea5babcc5dca417 + s4e087167cd0bac466344e72016511172 + re26f6ae180723793af62bc36d5ab2530 + ye1b53d01de118079a38de5e951586731 + g9fc5710c9266ce08afbe4da24702dfdd + k5cd5ea1bac40fdbb8b133b7e356809c6 + fcd6e4771e956e270c6897d24ca51c256 + y9d7854a5921fa2be88c8cd72c7e2884e + xa58bea1ecad6fe7d2c736aab1df2df44 + e4569f6c98804675f7117a84abb0b8d5c + o4d2081e2344020922dcb924690c9972e + af150185e5eef8ecd8dc1b0a4977c7d55  + "'>" + f32820e1c54cbc3fa0d418cd1c195eaec + y8c24ea00a7a1edf1c01f794d487697e3 + bcc0ad4f628e703f9ff6e25b87b77ec34 + c985c961c7ee85fe6a25d5a66fb421745 + z5ab4e3bdc353d621cea5babcc5dca417 + s4e087167cd0bac466344e72016511172 + re26f6ae180723793af62bc36d5ab2530 + ye1b53d01de118079a38de5e951586731 + g9fc5710c9266ce08afbe4da24702dfdd + k5cd5ea1bac40fdbb8b133b7e356809c6 + fcd6e4771e956e270c6897d24ca51c256 + y9d7854a5921fa2be88c8cd72c7e2884e + xa58bea1ecad6fe7d2c736aab1df2df44 + e4569f6c98804675f7117a84abb0b8d5c + o4d2081e2344020922dcb924690c9972e + af150185e5eef8ecd8dc1b0a4977c7d55  + "</a>")

//]]>;

</script></td>
```

out put is like this

```
<td class="generalinfo_right">
<script type="text/javascript">
same above script plus following Line
</script><a href="mailto:someID@email.com">someID@email.com</a></td>
```

Comment: this script should generate email but why html agility pack shows this script instead of generated Email

Comment: the script is to protect against spam. Still wondering, why you should try to get around it? If the site doesn't want you to collect those data, consider getting them on a less fishy way.

Comment: consider getting them on a less fishy way means? i am getting it for Legit purpose not for spaming

Comment: "Legit purpose"? you mean legal purpose? The easiest way would be, to ask the owner of the data. He might give them to you in your favorite format. No need to crawl the site ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own custom parser that will read the script and parse Email from it.here goes the code

If this code can be optimized or can be written more neatly please let me know

```
private string ReadEmail(string EmailScript)
{
  string EncriptedEmail = "";
  string dataPart = "";
  dataPart = EmailScript.Substring(0, EmailScript.IndexOf("document.write")).Replace("//<![CDATA[\r", "").Replace("\"", "").Replace("\r\n","");
  EncriptedEmail = EmailScript.Replace("\"","");
  EncriptedEmail = EncriptedEmail.Substring(EncriptedEmail.IndexOf("'> + "), EncriptedEmail.IndexOf(" + </a>") - EncriptedEmail.IndexOf("'> +")).Replace("'> +", "").Trim();
  string[] requiredVariables = EncriptedEmail.Split('+');
  List<string> ExtractedDataFromRaw = new List<string>();
  string email = "";
  foreach (string variable in requiredVariables)
  {
    string temp = dataPart.Substring(dataPart.IndexOf(variable),dataPart.Length-dataPart.IndexOf(variable)).Replace(" ","");
    string tempValueofVariable = temp.Substring(0, temp.IndexOf(";"));
    tempValueofVariable = tempValueofVariable.Substring(tempValueofVariable.IndexOf("="), tempValueofVariable.Length - temp.IndexOf("=")).Replace("=","");
    if (tempValueofVariable.Contains("String.fromCharCode"))
    {
      tempValueofVariable = GetCharacterFromASCII(tempValueofVariable.Replace("String.fromCharCode(", "").Replace(")", ""));
    }
    ExtractedDataFromRaw.Add(tempValueofVariable.Replace("'",""));
    email += tempValueofVariable.Replace("'", "");
    }
    return email;
 }
 private string GetCharacterFromASCII(string value)
 {
    int result = 0;
    int.TryParse(value, out result);
    return char.ConvertFromUtf32(result);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

That code is building the email address one character at a time from character codepoints and then assembling it later. I suppose this is an attempt to prevent email spam. Depending on what you need to do, it might be easiest to just pull the email address from the link using jQuery or something. $('a[href^=mailto]').attr('href').substring(7) or something ought to do it.

Comment: i am using c# desktop application  can we get jqury to work there